# Java IF statement not outputting correctly

Tags: java

I'm new to this site :)

Anyway, I decided to learn java a couple of days ago and I have a small problem which I don't know how to fix.
This is my code:
When name = Jim I want it to output "Hello Jim", when it doesnt  = Jim then output "Youre not Jim, youre " + name

```
import java.util.*;
public class app {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name;
        Scanner inputName = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
        name = inputName.nextLine();

        if (name == "Jim") {
            System.out.println("Hello " + name);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Youre not Jim! You are " + name);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (name == "Jim")
```

This is wrong. You compare Strings in Java with `.equals()`.

```
    if (name.equals("Jim"))
```

You should *always compare object references meaningfully*. Understand that the  `==` operator compares object references and primitive values only. You don't want to compare object references in this case, you want to compare the objects meaningfully. The `.equals()` implementation of the `String` class does that for you.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you! :) Sorry, I'm brand new to java, didnt know that!

Comment: @insideman11 No problem. You just made arguably the most common mistake of Java learners :) Good luck

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
 if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Jim")) {
```

Comment: Thank you :) I didnt know I could do that

Comment: @insideman11 No problem, Good luck with programming!